# how to left join tables without main one

Tags: sql

Has anybody an idea how to join below three tables into one? I have really no idea :|

```
create table A (id number, val varchar2(1));
create table B (id number, val varchar2(1));
create table C (id number, val varchar2(1));
insert into a (id, val) values (1, 'a');
insert into a (id, val) values (2, 'b');
insert into a (id, val) values (3, 'c');
insert into b (id, val) values (2, 'd');
insert into b (id, val) values (3, 'e');
insert into b (id, val) values (4, 'f');
insert into c (id, val) values (3, 'g');
insert into c (id, val) values (4, 'h');
insert into c (id, val) values (5, 'i');
```

[image]

Comment: You have enough reputation to know why tag spamming isn't  well received. Pick an RDBMS, and tag that and only that RDBMS.

Comment: As for the question, I suggest looking at `OUTER JOIN`s

Comment: ok, thanks. Will not do like that next time.

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks :)

```
SELECT COALESCE (a.id, b.id, c.id), a.val, b.val, c.val
FROM a
FULL OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
FULL OUTER JOIN c ON b.id = c.id
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do what you want uses `full join` and `using`:

```
select *
from a full join
     b
     using (id) full join
     c
     using (id)
order by id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9c02a8aad03ef37f11247581d4730659) is a db<>fiddle.  This uses Oracle because of the `varchar2()`.

Your